# Word better than RISING for someone in between undergraduate years describing the year that that person will be at?

Tags: single-word-requests

I received an email from a young student who said that she is *a rising junior*.  I eventually realized that she means that since she is currently enjoying her summer break, she has not yet begun her third year undergraduate studies, so will be a junior once the summer break ends and she resumes studies, but at this time she is technically still a sophomore.

Is there a better word than *rising* to describe someone in her situation?  One can change the verb tense - *I will be a junior* or similar, but that solves the issue through changing tense not finding a better word than *rising*.

One hears *an incoming freshman* or similar but while words like *incoming* sound fine when describing freshmen, it doesn't sound right to me to apply a word like that to a returning student.

I also don't like *returning junior* because then I might think that the person was a junior last year also and didn't accrue enough credits to qualify to be a senior yet so could be a junior again.  It therefore is necessary for the word to show that the person is both returning and advancing (but I like *advancing junior* even less than *rising junior* - I've already reviewed the obvious synonyms like *progressing*.

Any takers?  Is *rising* (and its close synonyms) the best that we can do?

.
EDIT: I'm continuing to research this on my own and I think a root problem is well captured [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/participles-and-gerunds)

> **Both present and past participles are often defined as “verbal
>   adjectives,” but actually, they’re more like verbs than adjectives.** [emphasis added]
>   The “-ing” verb in progressive tenses is a participle. Take a sentence
>   such as “Aardvark was skiing when you called.” You might be wondering,
>   “What’s the problem? ‘Skiing’ looks like an adjective in the verb
>   phrase ‘was skiing’.” It’s true that you could replace “skiing” with a
>   bona fide adjective, such as “happy,” and still have a grammatical
>   sentence. “Aardvark was happy when you called.” But look closer.
>   “Happy” can do things as an adjective that “skiing” can’t. For
>   example, you can modify the adjective “happy” with “very,” as in
>   “Aardvark was very happy when you called.” You can’t do that with
>   “skiing.” You can’t say, “Aardvark was very skiing when you called.”
>   .....
>   **To work through another example, take the phrase “falling snow.” You
>   can’t say “very falling snow,” so it’s probably not an adjective.
>   However, you can modify “falling” with an adverb: “gently falling
>   snow.” So we can conclude that “falling” is a participle.** [emphasis added]

Everything that applies to *falling* similarly applies to *rising*. *Rising* even when used as a *verbal adjective* retains the qualities of being *more like a verb than an adjective*.  So whether *rising* is used as a verb or an adjective, either way the listener expects that *rising* will be a continuous action.  But, in fact, the attainment of the undergraduate status of junior is a one-time, singular event.

However, I ran across the interesting term *oncoming* [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35219/what-does-rising-senior-mean-and-what-countries-use-it) as in *oncoming senior* where @Tom Au mentioned that he preferred it to *rising*.  I think it's a credible answer and hope that he adds it to the answers if he happens upon this thread!  The clear advantage of *oncoming junior* over *rising junior* is that while one is not in a continuous state of *rising* when waiting for the one-time moment when one officially begins taking courses as a junior, one is in a state of continuous expectation of that moment, therefore the moment of becoming a junior is continuously *oncoming*.

@Stephen Scott said *"Someone who has completed his junior year and will be a Senior in the following year would more accurately be described as a Rising Junior. Or, at best, a senior in incubation."* and his suggestion is based on the intuitive idea of *rising* for someone unfamiliar with the convention.

@Drew [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297112/am-i-a-rising-junior-or-rising-sophomore) makes his comment because, if you don't know the convention, *rising* is not a word that makes easy, intuitive sense.

A word like *oncoming* has the clear advantage over *rising* that even if one isn't familiar with the convention, the word *oncoming* has a very intuitive and natural meaning in this situation that anyone can understand.

Comment: What's wrong with *rising*?

Comment: *Rising* is the term I've used all my life, in the U.S. I'm not sure why it needs to be "better."

Comment: Why I don't think *rising* is ideal is because the present continuous usually indicates that something is, well, *continuous*.  The person is not, in fact, a *rising junior* in my opinion; instead the person is awaiting a discreet moment when their status changes from a sophomore to a junior.  If a man is anticipating receiving his US citizenship would he describe himself as a *rising citizen*?  Of course not.  This student has a continuous progression in terms of being a student but in terms of becoming a college junior, that is a one-time deal.  Rising is therefore not ideal I think.

Comment: I don't have a problem with *incoming*, though I can see that one might feel it has an air of "a new student" instead of "a returning student".

Comment: There are several fallacies I see in the quest  You say "she is technically still a sophomore" after completing that year, only no one else sees it that way. She is longer a sophomore, and 'rising' is the standard term. Analyzing such a set use as 'present continuous' when it's used here as adjective is not fruitful. It takes a village to raise a language, not one person who feels a certain way about an ideal form.

Comment: If she didn't recognize that she was not yet a junior there would have been no need for her to use the word *rising* at all; I believe it is understandable that she will use the term *rising junior* until she is actually a junior and then will use the term *junior* without *rising*.  I have limited characters and I think it was obvious that I understood the word *rising* was here being used as an adjective and compared it to other use of the term as an adjective; specifically, *rising citizen*.  If you are annoyed at my attempt to elevate language, please go focus your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20rising%20junior%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: [Oh look 58.6 million hits!  Which proves what exactly?](https://www.google.com/#q=I+could+care+less)

Comment: The word everybody uses for this is *rising junior*. You may not like it, but if you use anything else (other than longer phrases like *will be a junior starting September*), you won't be understood.

Comment: @Peter Shor and yet it's hard to believe that *oncoming junior* won't be understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term I used in college and high school was **oncoming** senior. This was in contrast to "outgoing" or "graduating" seniors who are leaving.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  As I mentioned in my edit, I had run across a post in another thread where you mentioned this term and I really like it myself!

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [***incipient***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incipient):

> beginning to come into being or to become apparent
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incipient)*</sub>

Sample usage:

> As an incipient junior, I am looking forward to all the laboratory-based courses that are now available.

Answer (score 0):

If the person is awaiting an outcome (like a final exam) that’s contingent on furthering their progression from one grade to another, you might consider using a form of “anticipation” that denotes their expected result. This is an example of what came to mind:

She applied for the position during her final days of the academic semester,      indicating her grade level as currently being an “anticipative senior”.

If the person knows already that they have passed/met all of the required elements for progression then it is perfectly acceptable to simply refer to themselves as already being a member of the next grade level.  If uncomfortable in doing so, they could indicate this instead by a simple tense adjustment like, “I will be a senior at the University of Hopes and Dreams this fall”…or something similar.